# MouseDoubleClick Event on DatagridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, double-click, datagridtemplatecolumn

How would I add an MouseDoubleClick event on my DatagridTemplateColumn?

My Column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PK"> 
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Name="pk" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Primary_Key}" Value="J">
    <Setter TargetName="pk" Property="Source" Value="/UserInterface;component/Resources/Images/key.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I now do it with an MouseDoubleClick Event on the DataGrid itself, but this offcourse fires on every doubleclick on any cell :

```
Private Sub dgColumns_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim dg As DataGrid = CType(sender, DataGrid)
    If dg.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing AndAlso dg.SelectedItem.GetType Is GetType(Attribuut) Then
        If CType(dg.SelectedItem, Attribuut).Primary_Key = "J" Then
            CType(dg.SelectedItem, Attribuut).Primary_Key = "N"
        Else
            CType(dg.SelectedItem, Attribuut).Primary_Key = "J"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This makes the column Image change, but only when I leave the cell, how would I do this instantaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to wrap your Image in ContentControl. ContentControl is a subclass of Control. MouseDoubleClick is defined in the Control class.

```
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="cc_MouseDoubleClick">
    <Image Name="pk" Source="my.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" />
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: That works until the Image is set to Nothing, then there is nothing left to click on. How would I overcome this issue?

Comment: Got This fixed by adding an border with a transparant background in the contentControl around the Image.

But i still need to unfocus to see the image in the datagrid change.

Comment: May be wrap it in something else?

Comment: It's strange. I don't need to unfocus to see image. Do you use INotifyPropertyChanged for your Attribuut class?